# How to assert/validate the JSON body and properties returned by a Micronaut controller

Tags: testing, controller, request, pojo, micronaut

I am a Micronaut/Java beginner and I am trying to design some tests for my controllers. I could not find many examples online so here is my question.
Below is the controller with 2 @GET requests:

```java
@Controller("/api/v1") 
public class MyController {

private final ClientNetworkList clientNetworkList;
private final ClientStatus clientStatus;

public MyController( 
    ClientNetworkList clientNetworkList,
    ClientStatus clientStatus
){
    this.ClientNetworkList = clientNetworkList;
    this.ClientStatus = clientStatus;
}

    @Get(uri = "/networkList", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_STREAM)
    Flowable<NetworkListPackage> packagesNetworkList() { 
        return ClientNetworkList.fetchPackages();
    }

    @Get(uri = "/channels/{stringParm}/status/", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_STREAM)
    Flowable<ChannelStatusPackage> packagesStatus(stringParm) { 
        return ClientStatus.fetchPackages(genesis);
    }
}
```

The java object POJOs:

```java
@Introspected
public class NetworkListPackage {

    private List<NetworkList> networkList = null;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public List<NetworkList> getNetworkList() {
        return networkList;
    }

    public void setNetworkList(List<NetworkList> networkList) {
        this.networkList = networkList;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }
}

public class NetworkList {

    private String name;
    private Boolean authEnabled;
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Boolean getAuthEnabled() {
        return authEnabled;
    }

    public void setAuthEnabled(Boolean authEnabled) {
        this.authEnabled = authEnabled;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }
}

@Introspected
public class ChannelStatusPackage {

    private String chaincodeCount;
    private String txCount;
    private String latestBlock;
    private String peerCount;
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public String getChaincodeCount() {
        return chaincodeCount;
    }

    public void setChaincodeCount(String chaincodeCount) {
        this.chaincodeCount = chaincodeCount;
    }

    public String getTxCount() {
        return txCount;
    }

    public void setTxCount(String txCount) {
        this.txCount = txCount;
    }

    public String getLatestBlock() {
        return latestBlock;
    }

    public void setLatestBlock(String latestBlock) {
        this.latestBlock = latestBlock;
    }

    public String getPeerCount() {
        return peerCount;
    }

    public void setPeerCount(String peerCount) {
        this.peerCount = peerCount;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }
}
```

And the potential tests:

```java
@MicronautTest 
class MyControllerTest {

    @Inject
    @Client("/")
    RxStreamingHttpClient client; 

    @Test
    public void verifyChannelStatusPackagesCanBeFetchedWithCompileTimeAutoGeneratedAtClient() {
        //when:
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.GET("/api/v1/channels/{stringParam}/status/");

        Flowable<ChannelStatusPackage> channelStatusPackageStream = client.jsonStream(request, ChannelStatusPackage.class); 
        Iterable<ChannelStatusPackage> channelStatusPackages = channelStatusPackageStream.blockingIterable();

        //then:
        //How to assert the returned body compared to the POJO?
        //How to handle the parameter in the request url?


    @Test
    public void verifyNetworkListPackagesCanBeFetchedWithCompileTimeAutoGeneratedAtClient() {
        //when:
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.GET("/api/v1/networkList");

        Flowable<NetworkListPackage> networkListPackageStream = client.jsonStream(request, NetworkListPackage.class); 
        Iterable<NetworkListPackage> networkListPackages = networkListPackageStream.blockingIterable();

        //then:
        //How to assert the returned body and compared to the POJO?
        //How to assert the returned properties ?
    }
}
```

Based on the previous code, how can I test that the returned bodies and properties of the requests matches the POJOs?
What are the usual test to be carried out?

Thank you very much for helping.

Comment: I have deleted my answer.  The comments you left under it don't make sense to me so I don't think I can be of much help.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normaly, the basic assertion start by testing the object type, so this should validate your schema.

An other way to test it is to use RestAssured, witch is a bit more readable.

You need to import the fallowing dependencies in you build.gradle

```java
    testImplementation("io.rest-assured:rest-assured:4.2.+")
    testImplementation("io.rest-assured:json-schema-validator:4.2.+")
```

You need test annotation processor to enable micronaut injection and junit 5 for the BeforeEach.
The full test dependencies:

```java
    testAnnotationProcessor("io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api")
    testImplementation("io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-junit5")
    testImplementation("io.rest-assured:rest-assured:4.2.+")
    testImplementation("io.rest-assured:json-schema-validator:4.2.+")

    testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine")
```

Then you can wright your tests like that:

```java
    import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
    import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
    
    import io.micronaut.http.HttpStatus;
    import io.micronaut.runtime.server.EmbeddedServer;
    import io.micronaut.test.annotation.MicronautTest;
    import io.restassured.RestAssured;
    import javax.inject.Inject;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

    @MicronautTest
    class MyControllerTest {
    
      @Inject
      private EmbeddedServer embeddedServer;
    
      @BeforeEach
      public void setUp() {
        RestAssured.port = embeddedServer.getPort();
      }
    
    
      @Test
      public void verifyChannelStatusPackagesCanBeFetchedWithCompileTimeAutoGeneratedAtClient() {
    
        given()
            .when()
            .pathParam("stringParam", "value")
            .get("/api/v1/channels/{stringParam}/status/")
            .then()
            .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.getCode())
            .body(
                "chaincodeCount", equalTo("chaincodeCountValue"),
                "txCount", equalTo("txCountValue"),
                "latestBlock", equalTo("latestBlockValue"),
                "peerCount", equalTo("peerCountValue"),
                "additionalProperties.key1", equalTo("additionalPropertyValue1"),
                "additionalProperties.key2", equalTo("additionalPropertyValue2")
            );
    
      }
    
    
      @Test
      public void verifyNetworkListPackagesCanBeFetchedWithCompileTimeAutoGeneratedAtClient() {
    
        given()
            .when()
            .get("/api/v1/networkList")
            .then()
            .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.getCode())
            .body(
                "networkList.name[0]", equalTo("nameValue0"),
                "networkList.authEnabled[0]", equalTo("authEnabledValue0"),
                "networkList.additionalProperties[0].key1", equalTo("additionalPropertiesValue1"),
                "networkList.additionalProperties[0].key2", equalTo("additionalPropertyValue2")
            );
      }
    }
```

This is not really the way you wanted to do your tests, but I hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. Your method seems clearer to me. With your example I'm getting these errors:
-cannot find symbol private EmbeddedServer embeddedServer;
-cannot find symbol @BeforeEach.
I did import the dependencies as said.

Comment: I also tried adding "import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;" to my file

Comment: I think you are missing some dependencies, i will edit my answer to give you full gradle imports.

Comment: "You are creating a client to call your controller, but you are never making the real client call. " - I do not think that is true, is it?  Both test methods shown in the question appear to making a real request.

Comment: This seems to work but how would you assert the type (string/integer/boolean) of the returned properties?

Comment: You assert the type with the "equalTo". The type of the value inside this assertion can't missmatch. If you value for a attribute is a boolean, you will have equalTo(true), not equalTo("true").

Comment: But "equalTo(true)" will assert the value not the type? I need to make sure the returned property types are correct regardless their values. In that case isn't it more appropriated to validate the response against the json schema or POJO object?

Comment: The equalTo(true) will only work if it's a boolean, if you try it with something else, you will have an exception.
If you really want to assert the class of an objet, you can use instanceOf() from hamcrest in addition.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up using the "hasItems" matcher or/and the jackson schema matcher.

```java
    import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
    import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
    
    import io.micronaut.http.HttpStatus;
    import io.micronaut.runtime.server.EmbeddedServer;
    import io.micronaut.test.annotation.MicronautTest;
    import io.restassured.RestAssured;
    import javax.inject.Inject;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
    import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasItems;
   import static io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator.matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath;

    @MicronautTest
    class MyControllerTest {
    
      @Inject
      private EmbeddedServer embeddedServer;
    
      @BeforeEach
      public void setUp() {
        RestAssured.port = embeddedServer.getPort();
      }
    
    
      @Test
      public void verifyChannelStatusPackagesCanBeFetchedWithCompileTimeAutoGeneratedAtClient() {
    
        given()
            .when()
            .pathParam("stringParam", "value")
            .get("/api/v1/channels/{stringParam}/status/")
            .then()
            .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.getCode())
            .body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("channelsStatus.json"))
            .body("keySet()",hasItems(
                "chaincodeCount",
                "txCount",
                "latestBlock",
                "peerCount", 
            );
    
      }
    
    
      @Test
      public void verifyNetworkListPackagesCanBeFetchedWithCompileTimeAutoGeneratedAtClient() {
    
        given()
            .when()
            .get("/api/v1/networkList")
            .then()
            .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.getCode())
            .body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("networkList.json"))
            .body("networkList.keySet()",hasItems(
                "name",
                "authEnabled",
            );
      }
    }
``
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `jsonPath` similar to Spring Boot `MockMvc` `ResultMatcher`:

```
testImplementation 'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.4.0'
testImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2'
```

Get the response as `HttpResponse<String>` and then use `JsonPath.parse(response.body())` to assert the json path:

```
@Test
public void verifyChannelStatusPackagesCanBeFetchedWithCompileTimeAutoGeneratedAtClient() {

    URI uri = UriBuilder.of("/api/v1/channels/{stringParam}/status/").expand(singletonMap("stringParam", "value"));
    HttpResponse<String> response = client.toBlocking().exchange(HttpRequest.GET(uri), String.class);

    assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, response.getStatus());

    ReadContext ctx = JsonPath.parse(response.body());

    assertThat(ctx.read("$"), isA(Object.class));
    assertThat(ctx.read("$.chaincodeCount"), is("chaincodeCountValue"));
}
```

Example for an endpoint test using [Micronaut](https://github.com/pavelfomin/micronaut-rest-example/blob/master/src/test/java/com/droidablebee/micronaut/rest/endpoint/PersonEndpointTest.java#L140) vs [Spring Boot](https://github.com/pavelfomin/spring-boot-rest-example/blob/master/src/test/java/com/droidablebee/springboot/rest/endpoint/PersonEndpointTest.java#L94)